# Vuelidate: validate on click, not when field touched

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onclick, vuelidate

I'm kinda new to vuelidate, and everything works fine, except I have no clue how to run validation only when the button <kbd>Submit</kbd> has been clicked. Right now it marks touched field red when you start providing any input and I'd like it to wait with that, till user wants to submit filled form.

Here's what I've got up to now:

```js
Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)
const { required, minLength, sameAs } = window.validators

new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  data: {
   user: {
     login: '',
      password: '',
      repeatedPassword: ''
    }
  },
  validations: {
   user: {
     login: {
       required,
        minLength: minLength(5)
      },
      password: {
       required,
        minLength: minLength(8)
      },
      repeatedPassword: {
       required,
        sameAs: sameAs('password')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
  background: #FDD;
}

.error:focus {
  outline-color: #F99;
}

.valid {
  border-color: #5A5;
  background: #EFE;
}

.valid:focus {
  outline-color: #8E8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate/dist/validators.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
`<div id="app">

  <input type="text" placeholder="login"
    v-model="user.login"
    v-on:input="$v.user.login.$touch"
    v-bind:class="{error: $v.user.login.$error, valid: $v.user.login.$dirty && !$v.user.login.$invalid}">
  <br/>    
  <input type="password" placeholder="password"
    v-model="user.password"
    v-on:input="$v.user.password.$touch"
    v-bind:class="{error: $v.user.password.$error, valid: $v.user.password.$dirty && !$v.user.password.$invalid}">
  <br/>  
  <input type="password" placeholder="repeat password"
    v-model="user.repeatedPassword"
    v-on:input="$v.user.repeatedPassword.$touch"
    v-bind:class="{error: $v.user.repeatedPassword.$error, valid: $v.user.repeatedPassword.$dirty && !$v.user.repeatedPassword.$invalid}"
  >
  <button :disabled="$v.user.$error" @click="$v.user.$touch()">
    Submit!
  </button>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could never really get used to the Vuelidate way of doing things, but, generally speaking, it works like this:  https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-basic-form

Setting it up like this allows you to have validation for each form input/element and then an overall check to see if the form is "dirty" and/or "invalid"

```
form: {
"name": {
"required": false,
"$invalid": true,
"$dirty": false,
"$error": false,
"$pending": false,
"$params": {
  "required": {
    "type": "required"
  }
}
},
"Age": {
  "required": false,
  "$invalid": true,
  "$dirty": false,
  "$error": false,
  "$pending": false,
  "$params": {
    "required": {
      "type": "required"
    }
  }
},
"$invalid": true,  <------- This is what you are after for valid/invalid
"$dirty": false,   <------- This is what you are after to see if the form has been used.
"$error": false,  <-------  This checks both invalid and dirty
"$pending": false,
"$params": {
   "nestedA": null,
   "nestedB": null
}
}
```

As far as using this in practice, one option would be to call validateform event on submit.

```
@click.prevent="validateform"
```

Then create a validateform method in your vue instance that checks

```
$v.form.$invalid  or $v.form.$error
```

then either display errors or call the actual submit method

Comment: The context is still helpful, but the link is 404

Answer (score 4):

Then the only thing you have to do after setting up the validations is to call a method that will validate the errors. So follow below:

```
<button @click="validate">Submit</button>
```

The method:

```
validate () {
  this.$v.$touch() //it will validate all fields
  if (!this.$v.$invalid) { //invalid, becomes true when a validations return false
   //you dont have validation error.So do what u want to do here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Right now it marks touched field red when you start providing any input

That means the field is getting "dirty" automatically but as the last version (Vuelidate 2) that is not the default behavior.

Please check if you have `$autoDirty: true` and remove it or set it to "false"

To do what you need using Vuelidate 2, you only need to call $touch() on the submit click event as `$autoDirty` is `false` by default. Check Roland's answer.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I do with **VeeValidate 3**:

```
<validation-observer ref="jobValidation">
 <form>
     <button v-on:click="nextPage()" type="button">Next</button>
 </form>
</validation-observer>
```

and within **methods**:

```
nextPage(): void {                 
    const validation = (this.$refs.jobValidation as any);
    validation.validate().then(() => {                 
    if (validation.flags.invalid) {                           
        // No no no no
        // bonus: show all errors in summary
        validation.$children.forEach((child: any) => {
           child.errors.forEach((error: any) => {
              console.log(error);
           });
           return;
        });
    } else {
        // Yes yes yes
    }
    });  
},
```

Comment: It's Vuelidate question, no VeeValidate